# SOAPUI : use operation with properties in Expected result

Tags: xpath, soapui

i'm using SOAPUI for my webservices' test, and i'm searching to make an multiplication with a property, to compare it to my result.

ex:

### testStep1(IMPORT) :

- **request** => `<hour>1</hour>` (Import of the value)

### testStep2 (JDBCrequest : EXPORT):

- **query** : `select * from myTable`
- **result** : `<hour>3600</hour>`(the value is stored in seconds in my DB)

### What i'm trying to do = Xpath match (Assertion into my JDBC Request) :

- "Xpath expression" : `//Result/hour`
- "Expected result" : `${testStep1#Request#//hour}*3600`

But it seems that "expected result" doesn't take this form of result.

Can someone help me?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your expected result you can use Groovy one-liner like so:

```
${= ${testStep1#Request#//*:hour} * 60 * 60 }
```